# Fetch inbox email using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gmail-api

I want to fetch user emails(readonly) using react and display them on screen. For login i'm using @react-oauth/google and Gmail API from google dev console account APIs. what are neccessary auth to get the access and below is my code with basic profile access. help me thanks in advance!

Below is my GoogleAuth login code where i'm also trying to get user email info but getting 403(Forbidden)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  googleLogout,
  useGoogleLogin,
  TokenResponse,
} from '@react-oauth/google'
import axios from 'axios'

interface UserProfile {
  picture: string
  name: string
  email: string
}

const GoogleAuth: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<TokenResponse | null>(null)
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState<UserProfile | null>(null)

  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (tokenResponse) => setUser(tokenResponse),
    onError: (error) => console.log('Login Failed:', error),
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      // Fetch user profile information
      axios
        .get(
          `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${user.access_token}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${user.access_token}`,
              Accept: 'application/json',
            },
          },
        )
        .then((res) => {
          setProfile(res.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))

      fetchInboxMessages(user.access_token)
    }
  }, [user])


  const logOut = () => {
    googleLogout()
    setProfile(null)
  }

  // Function to fetch inbox messages
  const fetchInboxMessages = async (accessToken: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages',
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            Accept: 'application/json',
          },
        },
      )

      // Handle the Gmail data response
      console.log('Gmail Inbox Messages:', response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching Gmail data:', error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {profile ? (
        <div>
          <img src={profile.picture} alt="user image" />
          <h3>User Logged in</h3>
          <p>Name: {profile.name}</p>
          <p>Email Address: {profile.email}</p>
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={logOut}>Log out</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => login()}>Sign in with Google  </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default GoogleAuth
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know how to do this using '@react-oauth/google and Gmail API' but you can do the same thing using Firebase auth (I really don't know if this helps you but if you want to try check this. **and also i copied and pasted your problem in chatgpt and I think he solved the problem I think you should do the same**)

FireBase.js

```
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'


const firebaseConfig = {
  // Api keys
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const googleAuth = new GoogleAuthProvider ()
export const auth = getAuth (app)
export const db = getFirestore (app)
```

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { auth, googleAuth, db } from "./Config/FireBase";
import { signInWithPopup, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import {
  doc,
  setDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  collection,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  async function loginHandle() {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuth);
      setUser(result.user);
      console.log(`You logged in as ${result.user.email}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  async function logoutHandle() {
    try {
      console.log(`Sign out from ${auth?.currentUser?.email}`);
      await signOut(auth);
      setUser(null);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loginHandle}>Log In</button>
      <button onClick={logoutHandle}>Log Out</button>
      {user !== null ? (
          <div>
            <h1>User Information</h1>
            <p>{user.displayName}</p>
            <p>{user.email}</p>
          </div>
      ) : (
        <h1>Log in in to see name and email</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```